# Dynamic email routing for listserv (in PHP)

Tags: php, forum, email, listserv

I'm doing some pro-bono work for a non-profit and need to cobble together some functionality, preferably without rolling it all myself. Here's the synopsis:

I have a CRM-like system that has Persons and Groups (made up of Persons).  I want to set up:

1. A dynamic email routing, so joe.user@mydomain.com is routed to the Joe User's email (as defined in the CRM.
2. Similarily, mygroup@mydomain.com routes the email to all group members (as defined in the CRM).
3. All emails sent to group addresses are added to a threaded forum.
4. Emails/forum posts can be held and aggregated into a periodic newsletter if a user prefers.
5. New posts are verified via a confirmation email before posting.
6. Forum threading and integrity is maintained as users reply to posts whether via email or via the online forum.

Much of this functionality is very similar to standard listserv apps or "groups" sites like Google or Yahoo "Groups", but the need to roll it into an existing php-based portal (Typo3) and have the dynamic email routing creates a unique situation.

Has anyone tackled this type of environment and what tools/tricks did you find helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the platform... These notes are based on a posix system like linux.

**[qmail](http://www.qmail.org/top.html)** (netqmail) is fast, powerful, and highly customizable.  It is very good as a base email system, and has well defined formats for integrating into other apps.

qmail supports advanced user routing and email options.

**[ezmlm](http://www.ezmlm.org/)** is a mailing list package built on top of qmail that is fast and handles most of the mailing list functions, including moderation, indexing, digests, and web archives, etc.